# Changing box color using jQuery on email validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have an input box which tests whether the email in the box is a valid one. This is the script:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  }
});
```

This tests for the email. I also have this script which would change the color by adding another class to the form.

`$("#myform").toggleClass("othercolor");`

Im just not sure where to put this code. Sorry for the newby question just new to jQuery. Thanks =D

Comment: this all depends on when you want the color to change. which is?

Comment: @DJ_Plus I want the color to change as soon as the text in the field is a valid email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Here's a demo... (UPDATED)**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajaraki/UANdt/)

It looks like you might be using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). Assuming that you are, you just need to initialise the form validation by executing `$("#myform").validate()` when the page loads (e.g. by putting it calling it from `$(document).ready()`).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").validate();
});
```

​ 
If you want to apply a CSS class when the focus leaves the email field, you could do something like this:

```
var validator = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    validator = $("#myform").validate({
      rules: {
        cemail: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        }
      }
    });


    $("#cemail").blur(function() {
        if (validator.form()) {
            $("#myform").addClass("othercolor");
        }
        else {
            $("#myform").removeClass("othercolor");
        }
     });
});​
```

​
`validator.form()` returns true if the form is valid, and false if it isn't. Note that .toggleclass() won't do what you want here; you'll need to add or remove the class based on the return value of `validator.form()`.

Comment: Hey thanks this was what I needed just didn't know how to put it together!

Comment: Good to hear! If you were to mark my answer as selected, that would be awesome. :-)

Comment: Sorry, went to bed late and forgot to mark it haha =P Didn't know StackOverflow had such a strong community, your from Sydney Im from Wollongong. =D

Answer (score 0):

why dont you add it into the success callback in jQuery:

```
$("#myform").validate({
rules: {
field: {
  required: true,
  email: true
}
},

success: function(){
$(this).toggleClass('red');    
}

});
```